# Alternatives to Jibble Web Server with php support?

Tags: java, php, webserver

Well at school we are not allowed to run .exe's (YES WE have windows... omg why, also you can't save DLL files) so when I needed an FTP server I just download a Java FTP Server named FTP-GO. We can run jar files, but only by double clicking on them, so we cannot provide any parameters. What I want now is a web server in a jar file which also supports PHP scripts, the disk limit I have is 100mb, of which I am using 25mb (but I can run jars from an USB stick). so if there is any equivalent to http://www.jibble.org/jibblewebserver.php which also supports PHP, which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) or [Der Herberlin Bremsserver](http://tools.herberlin.de/bremsserver/index.shtml).

Comment: Google is your friend: http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/examples/quercus-module/index.xtp